# How to make ajaxtoolkit autocomplete super fast and bind it on clientside

Tags: asp.net, ajax, autocomplete

I have used ajaxtool kit's autocomplete on a page which gets data from a web service. This autocomplete is slow, at the time I only have 10 to 20 records in table and it take about 3 to 5 seconds to search and show result in autocomplete. User have to wait about 4 second on average to see data.

I am not getting how to make it super fast please guide me. Is it possible to bind autocomplete on client side? My idea is if I get data with page load from server and put it in some array in JavaScript and as user click it get data from client side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be that you are getting the data from the webservice which may take a few seconds. Why dont you cache the data in the servlet itself(in a Hasmap or a List) and then periodically ( say every 2 mins ) calling the webservice and getting the latest.

Hence when your autocomplete plugin requests for the latest autocomplete data you will return the cached values and not the actual values from the webservice.

Comment: Thanks for replying me. Apache Fan dont you think getting data from web service is faster as it is in JSON. I am using ajaxtookit automplete which I am not sure but looks only work with web services. Please guide. Thanks once agian.

Comment: So what kind of business logic are you performing to build the list of autocomplete items? My Point is that if you can cache the list and only periodically recreate the list then you can really improve the performance.

Answer (score 1):

I've noticed that some sites will store the hash map/list on another page and reference that page from the autocomplete function. Therefore the loading of the said page will not be impacted, and the autocomplete will be extremely fast (practically instantaneous). Also, you can maintain that list at your liesure once a minute/hour/day/month/year and it will be completely independant of the users expperience.